# Ionic Installation issue (typescript)

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have used the regular `ionic start projectName` to open my project.

I'm getting TS errors such as `TypeError: Cannot read property "length" of undefined` 
and this is coming from a simple ionic task (`ionic g provider GoldService`)

I am not sure  but a good reason would be because I didn't runn the `--ts` attribute on the start project command.

My question is if I would need to start the app from start or can I remedy this situation with acquiring the `--ts` attribute into ionic in this current ionic project.

Comment: Same issue here, with Ionic 3 updated today.